# Parsing RSS feeds with PHP

Tags: php, rss

I am successfully parsing an RSS feed with PHP, but want to return a message when the feed is empty. I have included the 
[PHP File](http://pastebin.com/d76f5a79f) here to show you what I want to achieve.

I'm looking for it to break or stop executing, but print a message and stop at the point highlighted.

Thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DOMNode::getElementsByTagName returns a DOMNodeList object. To test if it's empty use its $length member.

```
if ($x->length == 0) {
    exit('etc.');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
die("Your error message here");
```

Comment: Thanks Robert, I used your tip but it does not stop at that point.

Answer (score 0):

Can you just use die() to drop out at that point?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways of ending the processing of a PHP script. The simplest way of doing so is to call the `die()` or `exit()` language constructs. You can also set a message using those functions, but then the program will not terminate successfully. Have a look at the [official documentation on exit()](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php).

In short, if you want to display some text then exit successfully, then use this code:

```
echo "whatever you want to say";
exit(0);
```

Else, simply use this code:

```
exit("whatever you want to say");
```

By the way, I edited your php code, my modification is available [at PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/m6e31f7a2). A diff with the original is also available [at PastBin](http://pastebin.com/pastebin.php?diff=m6e31f7a2).